# Identify a function's coefficients based on its values.

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

This is related to a question in The Math Connection on LinkedIn and following discussion. It goes as follows:

There is a polynomial and you have access to a function that evaluates that polynomial at a given number. You don’t know the degree of the polynomial, nor do you know any of the coefficients of its terms. However, you are told that all coefficients are non-negative integers. How many times do you need to call the evaluation function in order to identify the polynomial (that is, to figure out the values of its coefficients)?

***Spoilers ahead, think about the question first if you wish***

The conclusion was twice. 
Evaluation one is $P(1)$, where your unknown polynomial is $P$. If $P(1) = 0$, then it is easy, $P = 0$. 
Otherwise, evaluate $P(P(1) + 1)$ and express it in the base $P(1) +1$. The coefficients of $P$ are the coefficients of the base $P(1) + 1$ representation of $P(P(1) + 1)$.

As an example, given the original question constraints on a function $f$ and the following information, find $f$: $$f(1)=204$$ $$f(205)=1087670038021112932720656963356516921366795452188514173030853271504472$$

***Spoilers again - if you wish to think first***

$f(x)$ was found to be $99*x^{29} + 98*x + 7$

Thus, my real question arises, how would we figure out what $f$ is in the above example? I've milled over it, and I can't think of any way to do it other than using a computer program. Is there any nice way to find $f$ without use of a computer? If we do have to use a computer how might the code look?

Many thanks for any discussion or help.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1087670038021112932720656963356516921366795452188514173030853271504472+in+base+205

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about that answer...

If $m$ is any integer
greater than
any of the coefficients,
then,
if
$f(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^d a_kx^k
$,
$f(m)
=\sum_{k=0}^d a_km^k
$.

If we write $f(m)$
in base $m$,
then this will be the
same as
$\sum_{k=0}^d a_km^k$
since all the $m$-digits
will be small enough
to not carry.

This reduces the problem
to finding an $m$
which is greater than
any of the coefficients,
and choosing
$m
= f(1)+1
=1+\sum_{k=0}^d a_k
$
does this
since each $a_k \ge 0$.

Comment: Exactly! Well put, I like that answer explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of evaluating f(205), just evaluate f(1000). Now the coefficients will be easily found within a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: Actually, I was particularly interested in the case you are stuck with f(205) and can't get anything else. However, I really like that idea you gave. Just choose n so that 10^n is bigger than f(1) and then you can easily read the coefficients within all the zeros in f(10^n).